# Yii2 testing environment guidelines for extension development

Tags: php, testing, yii2, integration

I am developing an Yii 2 public (MIT) extension to change some of the `yii\web\View` behaviours (minify, combine and many other optimizations).

I can do it easily. But I really want to write as many tests (codeception) as possible for it. This is where I am very confused.

I already have some *unit* tests (for example: testing a specific minifing, or returning combined minified result). But I would like to test the entire result and the final integration between my extension and the Yii2 web application using it.

I just would like some guidelines for this process:

1. Should I have a real (complete) app inside my extension for testing purposes? If so, should it be 'installed' inside tests dir?
2. Would you use functional testing ? (I think so because the `View` will *find* files in `AssetBundles`, *combine* and *minify* them, publish the result as a single file and replace the assets' urls by new url (i.e., the optimized asset url) inside the view;
3. Could you provide some very basic examples/guidelines?

I just would like to **highlight** that I dont intend you do my testing job, I really want to **learn** how to do it. This is why I really would be very grateful for any tips.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## My Own Guidelines

Ok, I've found my way based on tests inside [yii2-smarty](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty/tree/master/tests).

So, these are the guidelines for testing your own Yii2 extension development using phpunit:

### 1) The tests/bootstrap.php:

```
// ensure we get report on all possible php errors
error_reporting(-1);

define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
define('YII_DEBUG', true);

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/' . __DIR__;
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = __FILE__;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

//optionals
Yii::setAlias('@testsBasePathOrWhateverYouWant', __DIR__);
Yii::setAlias('@slinstj/MyExtensionAlias', dirname(__DIR__));
```

### 2) Create a tests/TestCase base class extending `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`:

```
namespace slinstj\MyExtension\tests;

use yii\di\Container;

/**
 * This is the base class for all yii framework unit tests.
 */
abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * Clean up after test.
     * By default the application created with [[mockApplication]] will be destroyed.
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->destroyApplication();
    }

    /**
     * Populates Yii::$app with a new application
     * The application will be destroyed on tearDown() automatically.
     * @param array $config The application configuration, if needed
     * @param string $appClass name of the application class to create
     */
    protected function mockApplication($config = [], $appClass = '\yii\console\Application')
    {
        new $appClass(ArrayHelper::merge([
            'id' => 'testapp',
            'basePath' => __DIR__,
            'vendorPath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor',
        ], $config));
    }

    protected function mockWebApplication($config = [], $appClass = '\yii\web\Application')
    {
        new $appClass(ArrayHelper::merge([
            'id' => 'testapp',
            'basePath' => __DIR__,
            'vendorPath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor',
            'components' => [
                'request' => [
                    'cookieValidationKey' => 'wefJDF8sfdsfSDefwqdxj9oq',
                    'scriptFile' => __DIR__ .'/index.php',
                    'scriptUrl' => '/index.php',
                ],
            ]
        ], $config));
    }

    /**
     * Destroys application in Yii::$app by setting it to null.
     */
    protected function destroyApplication()
    {
        Yii::$app = null;
        Yii::$container = new Container();
    }

    protected function debug($data)
    {
        return fwrite(STDERR, print_r($data, TRUE));
    }
}
```

#### 3) Create your testSomething classes extending `TestCase`:

```
namespace slinstj\MyExtension\tests;

use yii\web\AssetManager;
use slinstj\MyExtension\View;
use Yii;

/**
 * Generated by PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator on 2015-10-30 at 17:45:03.
 */
class ViewTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
     * This method is called before a test is executed.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->mockWebApplication();
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        $view = $this->mockView();
        $content = $view->renderFile('@someAlias/views/index.php', ['data' => 'Hello World!']);

        $this->assertEquals(1, preg_match('#something#', $content), 'Html view does not contain "something": ' . $content);
    }

    //other tests...

    /**
     * @return View
     */
    protected function mockView()
    {
        return new View([
            'someConfig' => 'someValue',
            'assetManager' => $this->mockAssetManager(),
        ]);
    }

    protected function mockAssetManager()
    {
        $assetDir = Yii::getAlias('@the/path/to/assets');
        if (!is_dir($assetDir)) {
            mkdir($assetDir, 0777, true);
        }

        return new AssetManager([
            'basePath' => $assetDir,
            'baseUrl' => '/assets',
        ]);
    }

    protected function findByRegex($regex, $content, $match = 1)
    {
        $matches = [];
        preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
        return $matches[$match];
    }
}
```

That is all! This code skeleton is highly based in the yii2-smaty/tests code. Hope to help you (and me in further needs).

Answer (score 0):

this approach works, but i had to make some small adjustments:

1. if you are developing an extension (in /vendor/*you*/*extension* directory) and the bootstrap.php file is inside a test-directory, the paths for autoloader and yii base class are most likely wrong. Better is:

   ```
   require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../autoload.php');
   require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
   ```
2. i have tested an validator class which needed an application object. i have simply created an console application inside the bootstrap file (append to end of file):

   ```
   $config = require(__DIR__ . '/../../../../config/console.php');
   $application = new yii\console\Application($config);
   ```